# Скрипт обновления Wordpress темы с github

Tags: php, wordpress

Переделываю этот скрипт (http://oddstyle.ru/wordpress-2/stati-wordpress/razvertyvanie-wordpress-plaginov-cherez-github-s-pomoshhyu-transients.html) под обновление темы. Всё работает, но после обновления тема оказывается в новой папке с именем типа "аккаунт-репозиторий-наборцифр", из старой папки всё удаляется.
Копаю третий день, не могу понять где искать проблему.

```
<?php

class Updater{
protected $file;
private $theme;
private $basename;
private $username;
private $repository;
private $authorize_token;
private $github_response;

public function __construct($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'set_theme_properties' ) );
    return $this;
}

public function set_theme_properties() {
    $this->theme    = wp_get_theme('irecommendz' );
    $this->basename = wp_basename( $this->file );
}

public function set_username( $username )
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function set_repository( $repository )
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
}

public function authorize( $token )
{
    $this->authorize_token = $token;
}

public function initialize()
{
    add_filter( 'pre_set_site_transient_update_themes', array( $this, 'modify_transient' ), 10, 1 );
    add_filter( 'upgrader_post_install', array( $this, 'after_install' ), 10, 3 );
}


private function get_repository_info() {
    if ( is_null( $this->github_response ) ) { // Do we have a response?
        $request_uri = sprintf( 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/%s/releases', $this->username, $this->repository ); // Build URI
        if ( $this->authorize_token ) { // Is there an access token?
            $request_uri = add_query_arg( 'access_token', $this->authorize_token, $request_uri ); // Append it
        }
        $response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $request_uri ) ), true ); // Get JSON and parse it
        if ( is_array( $response ) ) { // If it is an array
            $response = current( $response ); // Get the first item
        }
        if ( $this->authorize_token ) { // Is there an access token?
            $response['zipball_url'] = add_query_arg( 'access_token', $this->authorize_token, $response['zipball_url'] ); // Update our zip url with token
        }
        $this->github_response = $response; // Set it to our property
    }
}

public function modify_transient( $transient ) {
    if( property_exists( $transient, 'checked') ) { // Check if transient has a checked property
        if( $checked = $transient->checked ) { // Did Wordpress check for updates?
            $this->get_repository_info(); // Get the repo info
            $out_of_date = version_compare( $this->github_response['tag_name'], $this->theme['version'], 'gt' ); // Check if we're out of date
            if( $out_of_date ) {
                $new_files = $this->github_response['zipball_url']; // Get the ZIP
                $slug = current( explode('/', $this->basename ) ); // Create valid slug
                $theme = array( // setup our plugin info
                    'url' => $this->theme["ThemeURI"],
                    'slug' => $slug,
                    'package' => $new_files,
                    'new_version' => $this->github_response['tag_name']
                );
                //$transient->response[$this->basename] = (object) $theme; // Return it in response
                $transient->response[$this->basename] =  $theme;
            }
        }
    }
    return $transient; // Return filtered transient
}

public function after_install( $response, $hook_extra, $result ) {
    global $wp_filesystem; // Get global FS object
    $install_directory = get_template_directory(); // Our plugin directory
    $wp_filesystem->move( $result['destination'], $install_directory); // Move files to the plugin dir
    $result['destination'] = $install_directory; // Set the destination for the rest of the stack
    return $result;
}
}

 $updater = new Updater( get_template_directory());
 $updater->set_username('naumovtop');
 $updater->set_repository('irecommendz');
 $updater->authorize('your_token');
 $updater->initialize(); // initialize the updater
```

Comment: "папке" чего? Где?

Comment: папка, в которой находится тема, меняется по имени архива, скачанного с гитхаба. Например, тема называется irecommendz, но после обновления эта папка пуста, а тема переезжает в naumovtop-irecommendz-1.0.6-0-g02874313fd82d4fe8f1f5609a9fa6d905cd89b5a.

Comment: Заинтересовался вашей темой и решил вашу задачку если интересно код на github https://github.com/SashokNekulin/WpAutoUpdate

Comment: Это хорошо, что Вы дали ответ. Однако, в ответе следует указать основные подходы к решению вопроса. Дело в том, что ссылка ведущая на сторонние ресурсы может перестать существовать со временем и в таком случае Ваш ответ будет бесполезным. Из-за большого объёма кода поместить в ответ полностью его не всегда возможно, но возможно описать основные шаги, которые Вы приняли для решения проблемы. Подробнее [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) > [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)